# Py3: Can't open file /snapshot/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/invoke.py : No such file or directory

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to test the serverless lambda function locally using the command
Command

```
serverless invoke local -f send --log --stage test
```

Error

```
python3: can't open file '/snapshot/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/invoke.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This command is run inside the directory which has serverless.yml, requirements.txt, handler.py.

Unable to understand why this error occurs and what's the solution

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Unable to find solution. Using my AWS profile to deploy and check every time (bad practice but can't help if I can't test locally)

Comment: Can you try reinstalling serverless with npm. (npm install -g serverless) and then try again

Comment: Do you have virtual env active?

Comment: What have you done in terms of installation and setup? Are you using [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? Did you create IAM user and role? How did you create the Lambda function?

Comment: I used awscli. I have correct IAM role. I am able to deploy lambda function without any issue. Just that invoke local command gives this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.
The result of my `serverless --version` command is

```
Framework Core: 1.66.0 (standalone)
Plugin: 3.4.1
SDK: 2.3.0
Components: 2.22.3
```

## Solution

First, if you installed with the command of `curl -o- -L https://slss.io/install | bash`, uninstall it with the following command:

`serverless uninstall`

Next, install with the following command:

```
npm install -g serverless@1.43.0
npm bin serverless
```

Now the `serverless --version` command looks like this:

```
1.43.0
```

that's all

Comment: interesting. so you're saying serverless shouldn't be used with official site installation? why does it work with 1.43.0 and not with 1.66.0? is this basically downgrading to lot earlier version?

Comment: Downgraded because I didn't know why. Please tell me if anyone is working fine with the official download.

Comment: @kambe This solution is correct but its not related to the serverless version. in my case, the solution was just to remove the previously installed curl version using ```serverless uninstall``` and then installing using npm ```npm i -g serverless``` that did the trick. even with sls version 1.67.0 its working.

Answer (score -1):

The venv module doens't create a binary at $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/pythonX.Y like virtualenv does.

As a work around for now, create a python3.6 symlink:

```
cd venv/bin
ln -s python3 python3.6
```

Comment: I am using virtualenv. This issue isn't related to virtualenv/venv finding python3.6